# Chain promises with Bluebird, returning whichever are solved

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Suppose I have 3 promises:

- Promise A
- Promise B that depends on the output of A
- Promise C that depends on the output of B

Such that: `C -> B -> A`

I want to be able to return those that were resolved, which means either A, A and B, or A and B and C.

I obviously must start by resolving A, but if I chain them using `.then()`, whenever one of them fails, the whole chain fails.

If I use `.some()`, it expects an Array of Promises as input, so it doesn't work in this case as the promises are not independent from each other.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve (as opposed to *how* you are trying to solve it)?

Comment: This already is the _what_ and not the _how_.

I have to make 3 calls to 3 different API's. Each call returns a Promise.
For the first call, I already have the data. To make the next calls, I have to feed the response I get from the first one to the second one, and so on...

The thing is: I want to be able to successfully return the result of the first promise if it succeeds, even if the second one fails. In short, I want to return all the data I can.

Comment: You are describing an implementation. That's 100% "how" and 0% "what".

Comment: I'm not describing an implementation, i'm describing what I need to solve, and the steps I have tried.

Comment: Can always resolve full chain if you use catch() for each promise and return from that

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special is required, just `then` and `catch` (or equivalent in your promise library).

Have the promises share an enclosing scope where the intermediate results can be accumulated.

```
var results = {};
return doA().then(function(a) {
    results.a = a;
    return doB(a);
}).then(function(b) {
    results.b = b;
    return doC(b);
}).then(function(c) {
    results.c = c;
    return results;
}).catch(function(error) {
    results.error = error;
    return results;
});
```

Comment: I would suggest reducing duplication by deleting the two `return results;` and adding a `.then(function () { return results; });` at the end. That's just my preference though.

Answer (score 1):

For a reusable scheme, here's a table-driven approach where you just pass in a list of functions and tags and it calls them one after the other, feeding the previous result to the next until one rejects.

If the resulting promise fulfills, then the resolved value is an object with all the results on the desired tagged properties.  If any of the operations rejects, the overall promise will reject and the reject reason will be an object that contains both the error and all the results collected before the error:

```
function processList(list, initialArg) {
    var results = {};
    return sequence.reduce(function(p, item) {
        return p.then(function(arg) {
            // run the next item in the list and collect its result
            return item.fn(arg).then(function(result) {
                results[list[item.tag]] = result;
                return result;
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve(initialArg)).then(function() {
        // return all results
        return results;
    }, function(err) {
        // there was an error, return both the error and the results we have so far
        throw {err, results};
    });
}


// example usage
var sequence = [{fn: fnA, tag:"a"}, {fn: fnB, tag:"b"}, {fn: fnC, tag:"c"}];
processList(sequence, "whatever").then(function(results) {
    // all results here
    // results.a, results.b, results.c
}, function(errResults) {
    var err = errResults.err;
    var partialResults = errResults.results;
});
```

You could also change `processList() to always resolve and to resolve with an object that contains an err property which you could check.  Which way to go depends a bit on how you want to use the results.

```
function processList(list, initialArg) {
    var results = {};
    return sequence.reduce(function(p, item) {
        return p.then(function(arg) {
            // run the next item in the list and collect its result
            return item.fn(arg).then(function(result) {
                results[list[item.tag]] = result;
                return result;
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve(initialArg)).then(function() {
        // return all results
        return {err:0, results: results};
    }, function(err) {
        // there was an error, return both the error and the results we have so far
        return {err, results};
    });
}


// example usage
var sequence = [{fn: fnA, tag:"a"}, {fn: fnB, tag:"b"}, {fn: fnC, tag:"c"}];
processList(sequence, "whatever").then(function(results) {
    // promise always fulfills
    // results.err tells you if there was an error or not
    // results.a, results.b, results.c contain whatever results completed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these are promises, you can absolutely manipulate all three at the same time, but I don't think `.some()` will do the job here.

`Promise.filter()` with some error handling is one way to go:

```
var pA = asyncOperation();
var pB = pA.then(operationThatDependsOnA);
var pC = pB.then(operationThatDependsOnB);

// map pA, pB, and pC to promises that will resolve to null if their original promise fails
var safePromises = [pA, pB, pC].map(function (p) { 
    return p.catch(function () { return null; });
});

// filter the results to the ones that succeeded
Promise
    .filter(safePromises, function (value) { return value !== null; })
    .then(function (results) {
        // results contains whichever promises succeeded, in the order A, B, C
        console.log(results);
    });
```

Another option is to use `.reflect()` as an alternative to catching the errors yourself:

```
var pA = asyncOperation();
var pB = pA.then(operationThatDependsOnA);
var pC = pB.then(operationThatDependsOnB);

Promise
    .filter(
        [pA, pB, pC].map(function (p) { return p.reflect(); }),
        function (inspection) { return inspection.isFulfilled(); }
    )
    .map(function (inspection) { return inspection.value(); })
    .then(function (results) {
        // results contains whichever promises succeeded, in the order A, B, C
        console.log(results);
    });
```

Comment: I liked the first solution best, it's readable and clever. 
Will try this monday morning! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special is needed, If along the way a failure happens, you can use failure handlers first to handle the error the way you like and then return the next promise such as ;

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                                           var r = ~~(Math.random()*100);
                                           r > 49 ? resolve(r) : reject(r);
                                         });
var p2 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                                           var r = ~~(Math.random()*100);
                                           r > 49 ? resolve(r) : reject(r);
                                         });
var p3 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                                           var r = ~~(Math.random()*100);
                                           r > 49 ? resolve(r) : reject(r);
                                         });
p1.then(v => {console.log("p1 resolved to " + v);
              return p2;},
        v => {console.log("p1 rejected by " + v);
              return p2;}
       )
  .then(v => {console.log("p2 resolved to " + v);
              return p3;},
        v => {console.log("p2 rejected by " + v);
              return p3;}
       )
  .then(v => console.log("p3 resolved to " + v),
        v => console.log("p3 rejected by " + v)
       );
```

As per Roamer-1888 comment on the promise dependency matter the above code can be modified as follows where promises resolve if a random value generated is bigger than the value obtained from the previous promise;

```js
function nextPromise(v){
  var r = ~~(Math.random()*100);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => r > v ? resolve(r) : reject(r));
}


var pA = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                                           var r = ~~(Math.random()*100);
                                           r > 49 ? resolve(r) : reject(r);
                                         });

pA.then(v => {console.log("pA resolved to " + v);
              return nextPromise(v);},
        v => {console.log("pA rejected by " + v);
              return nextPromise(v);}
       )
  .then(v => {console.log("pB resolved to " + v);
              return nextPromise(v);},
        v => {console.log("pB rejected by " + v);
              return nextPromise(v);}
       )
  .then(v => console.log("pC resolved to " + v),
        v => console.log("pC rejected by " + v)
       );
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question's characteristic that C depends on B depends on A. Handling results in a then chain is not the same thing.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 What i just wanted to demonstrate was, how it would be possible to handle the error and continue with the chain. But yes you are right p1, p2 and p3 are independent. I now added a new snippet to demonstrate the same functionality with dependent promises. So in the second snippet returned promises resolve if they are bigger than the previous promise return value and will continue even if rejected.